# Uipath needed licenses from abbyy

Tags: pdf, sdk, extract, uipath, abbyy

I am creating a automated process for bank and i need to extract data from pdf so as iam developer user in uipath, i can use Abby flexicapture SDK am I right?

In case the process developed and an attached user will use it, do he needs flexicapture SDK as well

or shall the bank install complete flexi capture system?
dalia

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You need ABBYY licence sdk for data extraction.

You can you use ABBYY connector for UiPath to export data to queue or can use ABBYY activities in UiPath.